# TypeError: "x" is not a constructor usando el módulo jspdf

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

**[RESUELTO]**

Bueno ya encontré la **solución al problema**. la aplicación usa **systemjs** para implementar las cargas de los ficheros js compilados por tsc.

En este caso, correctamente añadía el fichero en el apartado src del fichero systemjs.config.js

```
'jspdf': 'npm:jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js'
```

Pero, **faltó añadir la siguiente línea en el mismo fichero**

```
packages: {
    src: {
        main: 'Js/angular/src/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'jspdf': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
```

Con esto se resuelve el problema.

---

Llevo unos días peleándome con un proyecto en Visual Studio que trabaja con Angular y Typescript.

He descargado desde npm el paquete jspdf y me está dando la lata a la hora de usarlo.

Por un lado, tengo un componente donde se trabaja con la librería. Dicho código es el siguiente:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'c-imprimir',
    templateUrl: './imprimir.component.html'
})
export class Imprimir
{
    documento: any;
    constructor() { }

    onImprimir() {

        try {
            documento = new jspdf();
            documento.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
            documento.save('a4.pdf');
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof TypeError) {
                console.log("ERR [EXPLICIT] name: " + e.name);
                console.log("Message: " + e.message);
                console.log("=======================================================");
            } else {
                console.log("ERR [INEXPLICIT] name: " + e.name);
                console.log("Message: " + e.message);
                console.log("=======================================================");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando entro en la vista que carga este componente, **recibo el error siguiente en la consola del navegador**:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at evaluate (evaluate.js:106)
    at instantiate.js:394
    at dynamicExecute (register-loader.js:665)
    at doEvaluate (register-loader.js:612)
    at ensureEvaluate (register-loader.js:520)
    at register-loader.js:538
    at Object.eval (imprimir.component.ts:5)
    at eval (imprimir.component.ts:12)
    at eval (imprimir.component.ts:12)
(anonymous) @ initialize.js:1
```

Mirando las posibles causas de esto en internet, encontré que **añadiendo en el fichero systemjs.config.js** el fichero del módulo que se desea usar puede resolverlo, así que lo añadí en el apartado de src tal que así:

```
'jspdf': 'npm:jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js'
```

Esto, elimina el error anterior, pero, ahora viene lo siguiente. Ahora cuando doy al botón de Imprimir que llama a la función onImprimir del componente Imprimir, la consola de comandos me indica lo siguiente:

```
TypeError: "jspdf" is not a constructor
```

La verdad es que he intentado buscar una solución a esto he incluso [he visto que a más gente le pasa lo mismo en los issues de jspdf en Git](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/956), pero sin dar una solución exacta.

Lo curioso es que si a pesar del error, ***en la consola del navegador ejecuto un new de jspdf funciona perfectamente***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A alguien se le ocurre que puedo estar haciendo mal o qué podría hacer?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Estás obviando que Javascript distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas: en tu componente has puesto `new jspdf();`, en consola has puesto `new jsPDF();`. No es lo mismo

Comment: Lo he probado de las dos maneras pero sigue sin funciona, se me olvidó comentar esa parte. Lo que si que estoy viendo es que tanto el jspdf como el html2canvas, si los agrego por npm tengo que incluir dichos ficheros en el systemjs.config.js para que no me de el error de 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'' y aesto si que no le veo sentido